# How to automate sending warning email if USB backup drives are not rotated frequently enough?

Tags: windows, email, backup

Our off-site backup system relies on a staff member alternating which USB drive is connected to the file server each week.

Whichever drive is connected then synchronizes with the data partition on the server (nightly at 10pm) using a scheduled batch file, which runs Robocopy. The USB drives themselves are both encrypted using Truecrypt to protect our organization in the event of either of them being lost or stolen.

The weak (human dependent) link in our backup system is the staff member responsible for rotating the drives each week. Sometimes, he not only forgets to do this on the required weekly basis but for well over a month.

I already have logging set up which allows me to track when the drives are rotated thanks to the answer from my earlier question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/532196/script-needed-to-log-the-name-of-attached-usb-drive-to-text-file). So we already have a log file which tracks which drive is connected for any given day.

What I now want to do is to have an automatic email sent from the server (SBS 2003) to the user responsible for rotating the drives, the user's boss and myself (sysadmin) if the backup schedule is being missed for two or more weeks. Outlook 2010 is not currently installed on the server but could be if necessary.

Data in the log which tracks which backup drive is connected is in the following format:

```
Volume in drive V is BACKUP 1
Sat 05/10/2014 
22:00:00.77 

Volume in drive V is BACKUP 1
Sun 05/11/2014 
22:00:00.44 

Volume in drive V is BACKUP 1
Mon 05/12/2014 
22:00:00.39 

Volume in drive V is BACKUP 1
Tue 05/13/2014 
22:00:01.50
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I could automate sending a warning email if the same backup USB drive number appears for a certain number of consecutive times at the bottom of the log file? For example, 14 or more (as this would indicate the weekly drive rotation the user should have performed is now a full week overdue).

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: I notice three people voted to close this - without stating the reasons why. Does anyone have any ideas why people are voting to close this? None of the close voters were SMART enough to leave any feedback, so I'm just left trying to guess what their problem is.

Comment: Isn't this just trying to solve the wrong problem?

Comment: I can see why you could argue that, but I want this to automatically react on my behalf if there is a problem to save me having to intervene myself. Rotating the drives is already a part of someone's job description but unexpected things happen and things can get forgotten.

Answer (score 1):

This would work. You have to add the code for sending the email inside the if condition and change LOGFILE to whatever you logfile path is:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOGFILE="logtest"
COUNT=`tail -n16 $LOGFILE | grep "Volume in" | uniq -c | cut -c0-7 | tail -n1`

echo "Last tape repeated $((COUNT)) times"

if [ $COUNT -gt 3 ]; then
  echo "Sending email..."
  mutt -s"FATAL: Missing tape rotation" admin@youraddress.com < /dev/null
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any particular recommendations as far as code for sending email is concerned?

Comment: I use **mutt** for that. I've added the line in the reply now.